# Prove that $\exists v\in V$ such that $f_1(v)f_2(v)\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $f_1, f_2:V\to \mathbb R$ two non zero functionals ($V\neq \{0\})$. Prove that $\exists v\in V$ such that $f_1(v)f_2(v)\neq 0$

Can this result be generalized for a finite number of functionals?

I tried to do this by contradiction: Suppose that $\forall v\in V$ $f_1(v)f_2(v)=0$ then $f_1(av)=0$ where $a=f_2(v)$ and ussing the fact that it is linear but this is a contradiction because $f_1$ is not zero funtional. Hence $\exists v\in V$ such that $f_1(v)f_2(v)=0$

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely convincing because $a$ depends on $v$ and might be $0$ when you don't want it to.

The set $\{v: \, f_1(v) f_2(v) = 0\}$ is the union $\mathrm{Ker}(f_1) \cup \mathrm{Ker}(f_2).$ A union of two spaces is never a vector space unless one of the spaces you are looking at is contained in the other; in particular, the union of two proper subspaces could never be all of $V$.